# i can console.log a column accessor in react table, but it wont show on the screen as column data

Tags: reactjs, react-table

This should be fairly straight forward, but I am stuck. I have a set of columns that are defined with a 'label' and an accessor. The data for one of the accessors is nested inside my data, so I am mapping over the data, storing the value in state and trying to call the accessor from state. However it still will not show to the screen. I can console.log the data without issue.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { DUMMY_DATA } from '@/dummy-data';
    import TableHead from './TableHead';
    import TableBody from './TableBody';
    
    const Table = () => {
      const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(DUMMY_DATA);
      const [stateData, setStateData] = useState([]);
      const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        DUMMY_DATA.map(state => {
          setStateData(state.state.data.attributes.states);
        });

    const columns = [
      { label: 'Status', accessor: 'status' },
      { label: 'Name', accessor: 'projectName' },
      { label: 'Funding Source', accessor: 'fundingSource' },
      { label: 'Project Type', accessor: 'projectType' },
      {
        label: 'Location',
        accessor: stateData
      }
    ];
    setColumns(columns);
  }, [stateData]);

  return (
    <table className='border border-slate-300 dark:border-slate-600  table-auto w-full text-small text-left'>
      <TableHead columns={columns} />
      <TableBody columns={columns} tableData={DUMMY_DATA} />
    </table>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: `DUMMY_DATA.map(state => {`  Here you are looping the dummy data, but in each iteration you are re-writing the `stateData` hook.  You need to be creating an array in that map by `push()`ing each item to the array.  Then JUST OUTSIDE the loop `setStateData(yourNewArray)`